# Serial voting rep calculation bug

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page, down-votes, serial-voting

I was visiting my profile. I noticed a -43 change on my [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350209/cole-johnson?tab=reputation) header. Confused as to why I would lose that much reputation as I haven't done much the past few days, I clicked it. To my surprise, someone decided to serially downvote me for reasons unbenounced to me. Thankfully, the system reverted these votes and put my rep back to "normal".

However, my reputation tab appears to have miscalculated the delta since I last checked. All that was new since I last checked was a downvote on a question (-1), a serial downvote spree (-42), and a serial downvote reversal (+42). For some reason, the tab shows -43 instead of the actual delta of -1. I'm guessing this is a bug, but if it is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), please explain why.

[image: Bug]

Comment: Caching, it's always caching...

Comment: @Yannis It's May 26. The last reputation change that is shown is from May 24... I think a cache should expire after that long. Besides that, the reversal should invalidate the cache as it _is_ a reputation change, after all.

Comment: A ttl of 2-3 days would seem quite reasonable for such an unimportant piece of information... Also, it's May 27 (timezones are fun! ;). Anyway, it could be a bug, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's caching.

Comment: are you seriously worried about this being a potential bug? Like WHY worry about a 1 point loss in rep.. I honestly think you have lost sight of what these sites are for.. but them typical programmer mentality.. meticulous, thorough and pedantic (I am the same) ;)

Comment: Reversals do not get counted in the reputation tab total. They are not actual reputation events, but reversals of *previous* events. The total only gets updated when a new event occurs, not when a previous event gets reversed.

Comment: I was teasing all of us really @ColeJohnson it's ok, I shouldn't have commented