# Two kinds of Duplicate closing are too confusing - suggestion for a possible fix

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

[Question closed as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151418/152859) before [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/152859):

> [image]

[Question closed as duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181907/152859) after [Changes to "close as duplicate" (part deux)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/152859):

> [image]

This is confusing. This is two different designs for the same thing. To sum the changes up:

1. Different banner on top of the post.
2. Before: banner pushed as part of post contents and can be edited.

Worth to mention the "marked as duplicate by ..." message in the bottom is the same.

**Suggested fix**: simply run a script that within the same transaction Reopens all questions closed as duplicates before Feb 7<sup>th</sup> 2013 then closes them again as exact duplicates. If possible prevent this from bumping the question i.e. don't update the "last activity" time stamp.

Comment: The first screenshot doesn't seem right. It clearly shows `[duplicate]` for me in the title.

Comment: @slhck weird, for me too now. But it's not fake, trying to reproduce this.

Comment: Probably cache... Chrome has long and strong memory!

Comment: Wouldn't a script that just changes the banners directly make more sense than reopening and reclosing?

Comment: @Wooble no, the text has to be removed from the question body (Reopening already does that) and the new banner is added automatically, guess based on some field value.