# Provide alternative text for closing message on duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request

Following discussion (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/is-a-rough-duplicate-without-an-answer-a-valid-reason-for-closure)), and advise by one of the moderators of Cross Validated, I am posting this here as a feature request, since I think it is an SE-wide feature.

**Issue: Message accompanying the closing of a question as a duplicate.**
Either through "close" or "flag", currently the message reads "This question has been asked before and already has an answer".

But in reality the following may happen:

1. The older question has upvoted/accepted answers
2. The older question has answers none of which is upvoted or accepted
3. The older question has no answers but has comments, sometimes extensive
4. The older question has no answers and no comments

I understand that in cases 2-4 only moderators can close the newer question as a duplicate. But whatever is the case, **it is preferable not to leave duplicate questions both open.** 
So one of the two questions should close as a duplicate.

Obviously, for cases 1-2 the current message is adequate.

But if we have cases 3-4, then a) the accompanying message becomes absurd and b) it may be the case (especially for case 4) that it is preferable to close the older question, since newer questions have more chances of being answered. It is good that both cases are handled only by moderators.

So **the feature-request is that moderators should be able to**

1. Close an older question as a duplicate of a newer one (in case the SE engine checks time stamps and does not permit such a thing to happen)
2. Select from a list the text message that is appropriate for each situation.

### My suggestions:

- For cases 1-2 the current message is fine.
- For cases when the moderators decide to close the newer question, the message could read simply "This question has been asked before".
- For cases where the moderators decide to close the older question, the message could read "This question has become a duplicate".

Of course, in all four cases the link to the question that remains open should be provided .

(Note: the case where both questions have received answers is compatible with the above proposed messages, and it is up to the moderators to decide what to do in this case).

Comment: For cases 2 through 4, the message *does* change - to: *"This question is an exact duplicate of:"* -- See: [What decides what to prepend the duplicate question list with on a duplicate question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197452/what-decides-what-to-prepend-the-duplicate-question-list-with-on-a-duplicate-que)

Comment: Without answers it is much harder to know if two questions are duplicates or not. That's why only moderators do it. And the message is different as commented above.

Comment: @KateGregory As I clearly stated in my question I have no issue with cases 2-4 being handled only by moderators, on the contrary. As for the alternative message, I don't see how the word "exact" relates logically in a one-to-one relationship with the case of an older question with no answers, but, it is better than nothing. Do you know whether moderators can close an older question as being a duplicate of a newer question?