# Why are there different texts for duplicate questions?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](/q/48037/350567) and saw a different duplicate text from what it usually is:

> **Possible duplicate:** {link}

And I randomly picked [another duplicate question](/q/285385/350567) from the front page, where the text says regularly:

> **This question already has an answer here:** {link}

What's the reason for the difference?

Comment: Also see [What decides what to prepend the duplicate question list with on a duplicate question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197452/what-decides-what-to-prepend-the-duplicate-question-list-with-on-a-duplicate-que)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Possible duplicate** message is from older times. You can actually [view the revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/48037/revisions) and see it's an automatically inserted text which is now part of the question's body.

[image]

The corresponding close reason type is 1 – Exact Duplicate in SEDE and the data dump.

**This question already has an answer here** is used for questions which were closed more recently, and it's a banner which is generated separately from the question. The close reason type here is 101 – Duplicate.

Comment: Good answer. This also explains why the PD text is bigger than the TQAHAAH text.

Comment: Do you know when the change was made?

Comment: @iDebug [February 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166514/295232), it seems.